# Gnome error during login

Tags: gnome, login, login-screen, 23.10

At the time of login in Ubuntu 23.10 & gnome 45.1, I'm faced with this screen.

[image]

after repeated attempts of logging-out & restarting, it finally lets me in.

I tried to pull some logs using:

```
>gnome -xe | grep gnome
```

I tried disabling all the external gnome extensions. And the built-in `Ubuntu App Indicators` (as I saw some error thrown by it in logs). But inspite of that the problem persists.

Here is the full log of 3 attempts of logging-in & restarting

https://pastebin.com/raw/mLR5sLFg

I cant make much sense of them.  Help me please!

Comment: Have you tried launching gnome from another tty? if not, do

`Ctrl` + `Alt` + `2`

Enter your username and password. And then execute:

```bash
gnome-shell
```